# Как симулировать расширение экрана?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser, экран, браузер

https://www.esolutions.se/whatsmyinfo `Screen Resolution`

Нашел плагин для старенькой Opera 11, 12 версии. А что то новее есть?

Comment: В хроме есть встроенная фича.

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите F12, появится панель разработчика, потом ctrl+shift+m и в полях можете задать нужное разрешение